# Spring Constraint Validation Context - Database Request Caching

Tags: spring, validation, caching, spring-boot, bean-validation

I've written a custom Validation Annotation and a `ConstraintValidator` implementation, which uses a Spring Service (and executes a Database Query):

```
public class MyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyValidationAnnotation, String> {
    private final MyService service;

    public MyValidator(MyService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(MyValidationAnnotation constraintAnnotation) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return service.exists(value);
    }
}
```

It's used like this:

```
public class MyEntity {
    @Valid
    List<Foo> list;
}

public class Foo {
    @MyValidationAnnotation
    String id;
}
```

This works quite nice, **but** `service.exists(value)` is getting called for every item within the `list`, which is correct, but could/should be optimized.

### Question:

When validating an instance of `MyEntity`, I'd like to **cache** the results of the `service.exists(value)` calls.

I **don't** want to use a `static HashMap<String, Boolean>`, because this would cache the results for the entire application lifetime.

Is it possible to access some kind of Constraint Validation Context, which only exists while **this particular validation** is running, so I can put there the cached results?

Or do you have some other solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Spring's [cache](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) support**. There might be other parts in the application which needs caching and this can be reused. And the setup is very simple too. And it will keep your code neat and readable.

You can cache your service calls. You need to put annotation on your service methods and a little bit of configuration.

And for cache provider you can use [Ehcache](http://www.ehcache.org/). You have many options like setting ttl and max number of elements that can be cached and eviction policy etc etc if needed.

Or you can implement your own cache provider if your needs are simple. And  if it is web request, In this cache you may find ThreadLocal to be useful.  you can do all caching for this running thread using threadlocal. When the request is processed you can clear the threadlocal cache.